# What is a label's purpose in a "next" statement?

Tags: perl

In Perl, how do I use the `next` statement? In all sample programs I see the statement expressed like this: `next LINEP`

I do not understand what that label is doing. Can any one help me with an easily understandable example?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- Have a look of [next LABEL](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/next.html).
- It would be nice if you read the
  topic **Loop labels** from **Chapter 6 Control Structures** in
  **[Perl Best Practices](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596001735) by Damian Conway**
  that will explain you "Label every
  loop that is exited explicitly and
  use the label with every '**next**', last
  or redo".

Then you will come to know why and how to use next command with Label.

Answer (score 3):

You can look at [perldoc perlsyn](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html) for information

Answer (score 2):

As the [good book](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/next.html) states, next is used to start the next iteration of a loop.  The loop being referenced in your example will have the label LINEP where the loop begins.